# Installing Teamviewer silently on android device from a remote location using java

Tags: java, android

I want to install the TeamViewer software automatically on client's android device remotely using java. I have researched about a number of third party tools for automatic installation of software but the problem is that each one of them needs user interaction/permission in one or the other way.

In my app I will disable the touch of the device after the user logs in and an animation will be displayed based on the real time data from the server. I want to install the software assuming that no user is present at the other end and no response should be needed to install teamviewer.(My app will not there be on Google play.)

I am very new to android development, but through my research I found that .exe file can not be installed on Android as its a Linux based OS.I was planning to keep the Application(.exe) file at server and then try to install it issuing some adb command from my code.

Can someone please tell me how is it possible? How should I proceed? Please help.
Thanks in advance for any help.

Comment: You need to let the device know that this is not malware.

Comment: You mean then I can run the .exe file directly on android device? And how do I differentiate b/w the Application file and the Malware?

Comment: Last time I heard, the installable files on Android were called *APK*.

Answer (score 2):

There are two way for installing an App on an Android device:

1. Via ADB. This requires Debugging to be enabled on the device, and the computer the Java program is executed on requires an USB connection to the device (and proper USB drivers) and the device must be "ADB-paired" with the computer if the device has at least Android 4.2. Furthermore you need ADB which is part of the Android SDK and therefore not present on a regular PC. You could ship a version of ADB with your program but ADB is platform specific (Windows, OSX, Linux, ..) therefore you would have to include multiple versions and select on.
2. Vis Google Play. Once the user is logged-in any app from the play store can be installed to the users's device via web interface. As the Google log-in credentials are required a user must be present to enter them.

Conclusion: What you want is nearly impossible, especially the "without user interaction" part.

Answer (score 0):

You can't install a app from other app without user interactions, that would **a big security problem**.

The one app that can it is Google Play for obvious reasons.